# Bash indirect variable referencing

Tags: bash, variables, reference

```
foo='abc'
bar='xyz'
var=bar
```

How to I get access to `'xyz'` when I have `var`?

I've tried:

```
$(echo $var)
```

and

```
$(eval echo $var)
```

I just get `bar: command not found`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use `bash` indirect variable reference:

```
${!var}
```

---

And of course can be done with `eval`, not recommended:

```
eval 'echo $'"$var"
```

**Why:**

```
$ bar=xyz

$ var='bar;whoami'

$ eval 'echo $'"$var"
xyz
spamegg
```

Th command `whoami` is being evaluated too as part of evaluation by `eval`, imagine a destructive command instead of `whoami`.

---

**Example:**

```
$ bar='xyz'

$ var=bar

$ echo "${!var}"
xyz

$ eval 'echo $'"$var"
xyz
```

Comment: Nice. but if you may include why `eval` is not recommended, that may make this more classy. :) ++

Comment: Also , the right term should be [\[ indirect reference \]](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/bashver2.html#BASH2REF) as the reference could mean both direct and indirect references.