# Can not understand why bash variables can not be assigned this way

Tags: bash

I am stuck trying to understand (reading [the GNU Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Operation)) why I can not assign a variable this way:

```
myvar=var
${myvar}=42
```

I would expect that after the second line, the `var` value is `42`, but all I get is:

```
command not found: var=42
```

I will follow the manual (certainly with errors in my parenthesised comments...) to explain better why I am stuck:

1. bash reads input from command line (in this case), and well ok let it read.
2. bash breaks input into words and operators (no quoting here so I skip the quote rule...). These tokens are separated by metacharacters (=${} are not a metacharacters so there must be one token: the whole line)
3. bash parses the token into simple and compoud commands (here I expect the '=' to be interpreted as assignment, ${myvar} to be the lvalue and 42 the rvalue).
4. bash performs the various expansion.(`${myvar}` should be replaced by `var`)
5. bash performs all necessary redirections (no redirection here).
6. bash executes command (so well here bash should assign 42 to `var`)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9938649/indirect-variable-assignment-in-bash

Comment: Yes I red this question already but my problem is not that i really want to assign a variable this way. 
I 'just' can not understand why it does not works the way i describe.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bash variable referencing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39277932/bash-variable-referencing)

Comment: Not really, it is related of course, my question is about understanding why the command I type does not work. I don't really want to find a way to do it.

Comment: Note that you *could* make the assignment work with another round of shell processing. This is what `eval ${myvar}=42` does. But beware of the pitfalls of eval'ing arbitrary code. This is the stuff security vulnerabilities may be made of.

Comment: Yes, i already red few things about eval and try to keep me as far as possible from it...

Answer (score 5):

The `=` symbol is not a metacharacter.

Let's first start with the first mention of variable assignment: [Section 3.4 *Shell Parameters*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameters):

> A *parameter* is an entity that stores values. It can be a `name`, a
>   number [for positional parameters `$0`, `$1`, etc.], or one of the special characters listed below. A *variable* is a
>   parameter denoted by a `name`. A variable has a *value* and zero or more
>   *attributes.* [...]
>
> A parameter is set if it has been assigned a value. The null string is
>   a valid value. Once a variable is set, it may be unset only by using
>   the `unset` builtin command.
>
> A variable may be assigned to by a statement of the form
>
> ```
> name=[value]
> ```
>
> If *value* is not given, the variable is assigned the null string. All
>   *values* undergo tilde expansion, parameter and variable expansion,
>   command substitution, arithmetic expansion, and quote removal
>   (detailed below).

(the text in square bracket is my addition).

And there are no mentions of `name` going through any expansions.

By the way, a `name` [is defined as](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#index-name):

> A word consisting solely of letters, numbers, and underscores, and beginning with a letter or underscore. Names are used as shell variable and function names. Also referred to as an identifier.

If we carry on reading a bit, we get to [Section 3.7.1 *Simple Command Expansion*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Simple-Command-Expansion), where we read:

> When a simple command is executed, the shell performs the following
>   expansions, assignments, and redirections, from left to right.
>
> 1. The words that the parser has marked as variable assignments (those preceding the command name) and redirections are saved for later
>      processing.
> 2. The words that are not variable assignments or redirections are expanded (see [Shell
>      Expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Expansions)).
>      If any words remain after expansion, the first word is taken to be the
>      name of the command and the remaining words are the arguments.
> 3. Redirections are performed as described above (see [Redirections](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Redirections)).
> 4. The text after the ‘=’ in each variable assignment undergoes tilde expansion, parameter expansion, command substitution, arithmetic
>      expansion, and quote removal before being assigned to the variable.

And again, only the value undergoes expansions.

---

Now going through POSIX specs, [Section 2.10.2 *Shell Grammar Rules*](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_10_02) mentions:

> 7. [Assignment preceding command name]
>
>    a. [When the first word]
>
>    If the TOKEN does not contain the character '=', rule 1 is applied. Otherwise, 7b shall be applied.
>
>    b. [Not the first word]
>
>    If the TOKEN contains an unquoted (as determined while applying rule 4 from Token Recognition)  character that is not
>      part of an embedded parameter expansion, command substitution, or
>      arithmetic expansion construct (as determined while applying rule 5
>      from Token Recognition):
>
>    - If the TOKEN begins with '=', then rule 1 shall be applied.
>    - **If all the characters in the TOKEN preceding the first such  form a valid name** (see [XBD Name](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_235)), the token
>        ASSIGNMENT_WORD shall be returned.
>    - Otherwise, it is unspecified whether rule 1 is applied or ASSIGNMENT_WORD is returned.
>
>    c. Otherwise, rule 1 shall be applied.
>
> Assignment to the name within a returned ASSIGNMENT_WORD token shall
>   occur as specified in Simple Commands.

where a [valid name is defined as](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_235):

> In the shell command language, a word consisting solely of underscores, digits, and alphabetics from the portable character set. The first character of a name is not a digit.

Comment: Did not read the whole answer (yet) but I am not the one calling 'metacharacters', the GNU reference manual does here : https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Definitions

Comment: @David, you're right, my first sentence is just plain wrong `:)` (I fixed it).

Comment: Now that i have red it entirely, it is really clear. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Step 3 does *not* recognize `${myvar}=42` as an assignment, because the portion before the `=` is not a valid identifier; it's an as-of-yet-unexpanded parameter expansion. In the Definitions section of the man page, a *name* is defined as

> A word consisting only of  alphanumeric  characters  and  under-
>                 scores,  and beginning with an alphabetic character or an under-
>                 score.  Also referred to as an identifier.

Note that `${myvar}` is not a name, as it starts with a `$`.

Later, in the Parameters section, an assignment is defined with:

> A variable may be assigned to by a statement of the form
>
>   name=[value]

Thus, `${myvar}=42` is *not* an assignment.

As a result, the word is left as-is until step 4, when the expansion does happen, resulting in `var=42`.

`bash` isn't looking for assignments anymore, though, so by the time you get to step 6, the word in command position is `var=42`, which cannot be found as a command. Put simply, an assignment is *not* a kind of command.

By contrast, `declare "$myvar=42"` works because the assignment is a side effect of the command `declare var=42`, produced by step 4, when executed in step 6.

Comment: Ok thank you, but then what is assignment ?
Should I be able to find the answer in the manual ?

Comment: `Should I be able to find the answer in the manual?` Yes, `A variable may be assigned to by a statement of the form

name=[value]
` from [bash reference manual shell parameters](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameters). The _name_ part doesn't undergo any expansion and is defined in [definitions](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Definitions).