# setting variable from Multiple sub variables bash

Tags: bash, shell

Having some issues with variables

I have a global variable as
test_server="test101"

I have another script which determines what type of server and lets say i got result as test
result=test

now i want to save the output of test_server in a variable

if i do below i should get

echo $actualserver

test101

This i tried .. but my end gole is to set variable actualserver to test101

Any thoughts please

What i tried so far

````
test_server="test101"
result=test
actualserver=${result}_server
echo $actualserver
test_server
actualserver=$(${result}_server);echo $actualserver
-bash: test_server: command not found```
````

Comment: Put a valid [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) and paste your script at https://shellcheck.net for validation/recommendation.

Comment: That said, the error message is straight forward, there is nothing in your system or within your `PATH` with a program named `test_server`

Comment: The construct `$(foo)` runs a command in a subshell. Are you sure `foo` is a valid command/executable ?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use an indirect variable reference, but that's not the right syntax; see ["Bash indirect variable referencing"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39277932/bash-indirect-variable-referencing) for the correct syntax. However, associative arrays are usually better for things like this, see [BashFAQ #6: "How can I use variable variables (indirect variables, pointers, references) or associative arrays?"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006)